# AppExtensionのToday Widgetで現在ロック画面なのかロック画面ではないのか？の判定

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift3

AppExtensionのToday Widgetで現在ロック画面なのかロック画面ではないのか？の判定がしたいです。
ロック画面では処理できないようにしたいため。

```
extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: nil)
```

で一旦アプリへ飛ばして認証させるっていう方法も思いついたのですが
実際にアプリへ飛ばないようにすることができず。

何か良い方法は無いでしょうか？

以下で解決しました。
返り値のDataのオプショナル判定で解決。257ってのが気持ち悪いのですが今回は致し方ないです。

```
func exampleData() -> Data? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.yourapp")!
        let lock = userDefaults.value(forKey: "lock") as? String ?? ""
        var data: Data?
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: lock) {
            do {
                data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(string: lock)!,options: Data.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
            } catch let error {
                let er = error as NSError
                if er.code == 257 {
                    data = nil
                }
            }
        }
        return data
    }
```

Comment: `NSFileProtectionComplete ` を使った判定方法もあるみたいですね
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/27934173/1155354

Comment: おお、素晴らしい、これSwiftだったらいいのに。
リライト大変だ。

Comment: 結局上のリンクだとうまく行きませんでした。申し訳ありません。

Comment: おおっ　そうでしたか。。！力になれず申し訳ないです

Comment: 大変大変失礼しました！
頑張った結果大丈夫でした！！
補足すると
ロックまでiPhoneの仕様で10秒かかるようです。